# Add dynamic field to create specific JSON format

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, forms, field

Im trying to create a form with dynamic fields to create a JSON to post like this

```
{
"cpu": "1",
"ram": "128",
"env": {
    "envname1": "value1",
    "envname2": "value2"
}
}
```

While i have no problem to create cpu and ram i can not figure out to create "envname" and "value" because envname should be in a dynamic added field the first column and the value in second column.

I also can not get the regular fields and the dynamic fields together in one scope.

Please have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/q9dcn7wj/3/
cpu and ram fields are ignored. When i change

```
    $scope.inputs = [{id: 'choice1'}];
```

to

```
     $scope.inputs = {id: 'choice1'};
```

the dynamic fields are ignored. How do i get everything in the scope to submit the whole form as JSON?

Comment: Could you provide some details on what has to be dynamic? `cpu`, `ram` and `env`? Only `env`? (according to your fiddle) Why do you display two text fields per env property?

Comment: like this: $scope.toSend = {}; $scope.toSend.inputs = [];

Comment: Well yes that is what is going to happen. "push" adds an item to an array. If you declare

        $scope.inputs = {id:'choice1'};

that is NOT an array.  Where as

        $scope.inputs = [{id:'choice1'}];

IS an array. So doing 'push' on something that is not an array is not going to add a value.

Comment: with dynamic i mean the input fields for `env`i can add/remove with a click on a button. the user can add as many `env` values as he want in  the form of `envname`and `value`.

Answer (score 1):

You are treating your `inputs` model as if it is both an `array` and an `object`.

I suggest you create a `variables` property on your `input` model and push/splice on that.

I've updated your [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/faceleg/q9dcn7wj/30/), relevant code below:

**JavaScript**:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.inputs = { variable: [] };

$scope.addInput = function(){
    $scope.inputs.variable.push({name:'', value:''});
}

$scope.removeInput = function(index){
    $scope.inputs.variable.splice(index,1);
}
}]);
```

**HTML**:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">

        <input type="text" ng-model="inputs.cpu" />cpu<br />
        <input type="text" ng-model="inputs.ram" />ram

    <div ng-repeat="input in inputs.variable">
        <input type="text" ng-model="input.name" />
        <input type="text" ng-model="input.value" />
        <button ng-click="removeInput($index)">Remove</button>
    </div>
    <button ng-click="addInput()">add input</button>
    <br />
<strong><label for="userDebugText">JSON:</label></strong>
<textarea id="userDebugText">{{inputs|json}}</textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: Thx this is one step forward but i also need the JSON in the mentioned format and key/value for `env`has to come from the two input fields. So in your Fiddle

`{
  "variable": [
    {
      "name": "value",
      "value": ""
    }
  ],
  "cpu": "1",
  "ram": "8"
}`

`name`should be the input from the left field and `value` from the right one

Comment: When the user submits the form, process your model to match the format you want

Comment: the json is now not nested anymore and i still dont know how to add multiple lines to `env`without `[` but `{`. i will play around with angular.copy. thx for this